# Show a set is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let the set T(8) = {all subsets containing 8 elements of $\mathbb{N}$}. Show that T(8) is countable.

Proof:

$T(8)=\mathop{\cup}\limits_{n=1}^\infty\{\{n,x_{2},...,x_{8}\}:x_{2},...,x_{8}>n\} = \mathop{\cup}\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_{n}$

Now $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\ A_{n}=\mathop{\cup}\limits_{m=n+1}^\infty \{\{n,m,x_{3},...,x_{8}\}:x_{3},...,x_{8}>m\}$

So $T(8)=\mathop{\cup}\limits_{n=1}^\infty\{\mathop{\cup}\limits_{m=n+1}^\infty\{...\}\}$

T(8) is a countable union to countable sets.

Therefore, it is countable

Is this correct??

Comment: The idea looks alright, though your proof seems a bit imprecise towards the end. You might find the following idea easier: consider the map $f \colon T(8) \to \mathbb{N}^{8}$ given by $\{a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{8}\} \mapsto (a_{1}, a_{2}, \ldots, a_{8})$. This is an injection, and $\mathbb{N}^8$ is countable, so $T(8)$ must be countable.

Comment: I'd put red ink on your `$\dots$`.

You can make your argument more rigorous by using an inductive argument. Prove directly that $T(1)$ is countable. Then, show that if $T(n)$ is countable, then so is $T(n+1)$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim I expect RedFalcon doesn't have a theorem that $\mathbb N^8$ is countable. But if so, your suggestion makes the problem trivial, of course.

Comment: @StevenClontz: perhaps not. But he does have the theorem that a countable union of countable sets is countable, which of course can be used to prove that $\mathbb{N}^{8}$ is countable. :) I see your point though.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Yeah we didn't really cover that, I'm studying for an Intro Theoretical Mathematics final.

Comment: I will try what @StevenClontz said about using the inductive argument. Thank you for your help guys!